# How large is the intersection of the root system of a subalgebra of a compact Lie algebra with the original root system?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional real compact Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{t}\subset \mathfrak{g}$ a maximal abelian subalgebra. Let $\Delta(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C})\subset \mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C}^\ast$ be the associated root system (where $_\mathbb{C}$ denotes complexification). Let now $\mathfrak{g}'\subset \mathfrak{g}$ be a compact subalgebra with the property that $\mathfrak{t}':=\mathfrak{g}'\cap \mathfrak{t}$ is maximal abelian in $\mathfrak{g}'$. Then the root system $\Delta(\mathfrak{g}'_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}'_\mathbb{C})\subset {\mathfrak{t}'_\mathbb{C}}^\ast$ can be regarded as a subset of $\mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C}^\ast$ by identfying ${\mathfrak{t}'_\mathbb{C}}^\ast$ with the elements in $\mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C}^\ast$ that are supported on $\mathfrak{t}'_\mathbb{C}$.

---

**How large is the intersection $\;\Delta(\mathfrak{g}'_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}'_\mathbb{C})\cap\Delta(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C})$ compared to $\Delta(\mathfrak{g}'_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}'_\mathbb{C})$ ?**

---

**Edit: The initial question was whether one has $\;\Delta(\mathfrak{g}'_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}'_\mathbb{C})\subset\Delta(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C})$, but this is rarely true, see the comment by Jeffrey. However, it still seems to me that the intersection should not be empty, at least, and the number of elements in it should be about half the number of elements in the smaller root system.**

Background: 
The original setting where my question comes from is the following. A compact connected Lie group $G$ acts smoothly on a smooth manifold $M$. Let $T\subset G$ be a maximal torus in $G$, which then also acts on $M$, and let $\mathfrak{t}$ be its Lie algebra. For a point $p$ in $M$ with stabilizer group $G_p$ and associated stabilizer algebra $\mathfrak{g}_p$ it is easy to show that $\mathfrak{t}_p:=\mathfrak{t}\cap \mathfrak{g}_p$, which is the Lie algebra of the stabilizer group $T_p$ of $p$ with respect to the $T$-action, is maximal abelian in $\mathfrak{t}$ (i.e., the identity component of $T_p$ is a maximal torus in $G_p$). I would like to know under which circumstances the root system $\Delta({\mathfrak{g}_p}_\mathbb{C},{\mathfrak{t}_p}_\mathbb{C})$ is contained in $\Delta(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Isn't this only the case for regular subalgebras?

Comment: It might well be the case that one needs such an assumption, but I don't really know. In fact, a reformulation of my question could be: What are the precise conditions under which the inclusion holds?

Comment: This is very far from being true. Every compact group embeds in U(n) for some n, but most root systems don't embed in type A.

Comment: As Jeff Adams points out, this will be far from true.   (I wonder if it can be made clearer without the "compact" set-up, just as a question about root systems in the Bourbaki sense?  Or is the compact origin essential?)

Comment: I now added some background information.

Comment: @ Jeffrey Adams: I don't understand this. Why does the fact that every compact group embeds into some U(n) imply that the root system has to embed in type A? For example, SO(2n) has a type D_n root system, which I think does not embed into any type A system, but the claimed inclusion of root systems in my question does hold, for example, for subgroups of SO(2n) of the form SO(2m) with m<n.

Comment: @ Jeffrey Adams: now I get it, thanks ;-)

Comment: The question is now a new one! :-)

Comment: The root system $\Delta(\mathfrak{g}'_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}'_\mathbb{C})\subset {\mathfrak{t}'_\mathbb{C}}^\ast$ should not be regarded as a subset of $\mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C}^\ast$.

Comment: Instead, the embedding $\frak t'\hookrightarrow \frak t$ induces a map $\frak t_{\Bbb C}^*\to (\frak t'_{\Bbb C})^*$, and you may ask whether the image of $\Delta(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C})$ contains $\Delta(\mathfrak{g}'_\mathbb{C},\mathfrak{t}'_\mathbb{C})$ or  contains in a large subset of it (in some sense).

Comment: Therefore, I suggest that you edit your question again...